# didSet and Getter in Swift array

Tags: swift

I want to initialise elements only if an array has been set from outside the current class. Looks like a use for `didSet`!

```
// external API
var arr: [Display] = [] {
    didSet {
        array = arr
        initialiseElements(arr: arr)
    }

}

// internal
private var array: [Display] = []
```

but when we return the value from `arr` it might not be correct - I want to use `array` as a backing store.

I tried to use a getter on `arr` but this isn't allowed in Swift. How can I prevent the use of `arr` within the class, or otherwise ensure we only `initiliseElements(:)` via calls outside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use didSet? why not set?

```
var arr: [Display] {
    set {
        array = newValue
        initialiseElements(arr: newValue)
    }
    get {
        return self.array
    }
}
```

**How can I prevent the use of arr within the class?**

You can't, swift doesn't have such access control

**otherwise ensure we only initiliseElements(:) via calls outside the class**

Again, you can't.

It makes no sense logically as well, think of what you are asking for, you are asking class to declare a variable which itself cant set (read only) but should expose to it outside class to write (read + write) it?

How is that possible? What is the use case you are trying to solve here? If for some reason you ended up with this solution, may be solutioning is wrong! re think of your implementation.

Hope this helps